# Exact value of a series question

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

The value of the series 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} $$
is well-known to be $\pi^2/6$ and there are many proofs of this
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem. How can one show that the seemingly related series
$$\sum_{n=3}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2 - 4}$$
has sum $25/48$?

Answer (score 6):

Hint: $\dfrac{1}{n-2}-\dfrac{1}{n+2} = \dfrac{4}{n^2-4}$

Comment: Thank you Thomas. Only the first four positive terms survive and the sum is 1/4(1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/4) = 25/48